# how to make synchronous call to json data from angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am calling some data from a `JSON` file in AngularJS but due to the asynchronous call the code is moving to other step before receiving the data so that is causing an error.
I used `$http.get`

```
$http.get('job.json').success(function (response) {
  $scope.big = response;      
});
```

Can you suggest some synchronous  method to call json data which is

```
{
  "days": [{
    "dayname": "Sun,23 Aug 2015",
    "date": "2015-08-23",
    "hours": "hoursArray(array24)"
  }, {
    "dayname": "Mon,24 Aug 2015",
    "date": "2015-08-24",
     "hours": "hoursArray(array24)"
  }, {
    "dayname": "Tue,25 Aug 2015",
    "date": "2015-08-25",
    "hours":"hoursArray(array24)"
  }, {
    "dayname": "Wed,26 Aug 2015",
    "date": "2015-08-26",
    "hours": "hoursArray(array24)"
  }]
}
```

this is the jquery file i am using

```js
(function($) {
 $.fn.schedule = function(options) {
  var methods = {
   init : function(ele, opt) {
    //methods.currentdate = methods.now.getFullYear() + "Engine Change" + methods.now.getMonth() + "Engine Change" + methods.now.getDate();
    methods.currentdate = methods.now.getFullYear() + "-" + methods.now.getMonth() + "-" + methods.now.getDate();
    // $("#scheduleAllDays > *").each(function(){
    // var item = $(this);
    // $("#scheduleAllDays").width($("#scheduleAllDays").width()+item.width());
    // });
    // $("#scheduleAllDays").width($("#scheduleAllDays").width());
    ele.find("[data-row]").each(function() {
     var drow = $(this), drowset = $("[data-row='" + drow.data("row") + "']");
     
     var maxheight = methods.elesMaxHeight(drowset);
     drowset.height(maxheight);
    });
    methods.allocateDurations(ele);
    $("#scheduleContentInner", ele).css("min-height", $(".schedule-drag-wrap", ele).innerHeight());
   },
   elesMaxHeight : function(ele) {
    var heights = $(ele).map(function() {
     return $(this).height();
    }).get();
    return Math.max.apply(null, heights);
   },
   allocateDurations : function(ele) {
    methods.flightdata = {
     routes : {}
    };
    ele.find("[data-flight-row]").each(function(i, ival) {
     var flight = $(this);
     methods.flightdata.routes["row" + i] = [];
     flight.find("[data-flight-record]").each(function() {
      var currentFlight = $(this), flightrecord = methods.makeStringToObject(currentFlight.data("flight-record"));
      flightrecord.element = currentFlight;
      methods.flightdata.routes["row" + i].push(flightrecord);
     });
    });
    methods.positionSet(ele);
   },
   positionSet : function(ele) {
    var dayelement = $("#scheduleAllDays > *", ele);
    
    var totaldaywidth = $("#scheduleAllDays").width() + 30;
    
    var totaldays = dayelement.size();
    
    var totalSeconds = (((totaldays * 24) * 60) * 60);
    var perSecondsWidth = Number(totaldaywidth / totalSeconds);
    var divider = $(".schedule-h-divider");
    dayelement.each(function(i, ival) {
     var dayele = $(this), dividerele = divider.eq(i);
     dividerele.css({
      top : $("#scheduleAllDays").height(),
      left : dayele.offset().left - 104
     });
    });
    for (var i in methods.flightdata.routes) {
     var iobj = methods.flightdata.routes[i];
     for (var j in iobj) {
      var jobj = iobj[j];
      var duration = jobj.duration, width = Number(methods.hmtosec(duration, ".") * perSecondsWidth);
      var parent = jobj.element.parent();
      jobj.element.css({
       // position : "relative",
       width : width + "px",
       overflow : "hidden",
       "white-space" : "nowrap"
      }).parent().css({
       // width : width+"px",
       // overflow : "hidden"
       // position:"absolute",
       left : (j==0)?0:parent.prev().position().left+parent.prev().width()
      });
     }
    }
    methods.dragInit(ele);
   },
   setCurrentTimeMarker : function(ele) {
    var marker = $(".schedule-current-time-marker");
    var markerpills = $(".schedule-time-marker-pills");
    var dayelement = $("#scheduleAllDays > *", ele);
    var totaldaywidth = $("#scheduleAllDays").width() + 30;
    var totaldays = dayelement.size();
    var totalSeconds = (((totaldays * 24) * 60) * 60);
    var perSecondsWidth = Number(totaldaywidth / totalSeconds);
    var currentdate = new Date();
    var format = currentdate.getFullYear() + "Engine Change" + currentdate.getMonth() + "Engine Change" + currentdate.getDate();
    var currentdateele = $("#scheduleAllDays").find("[data-date='" + format + "']");
    var days = (currentdateele.index()), seconds = ((days * 24) * 60) * 60;
    seconds = seconds + methods.hmtosec(currentdate.getHours() + "." + currentdate.getMinutes(), ".");
    marker.stop().animate({
     top : $("#scheduleAllDays",ele).height()-53,
     left : (seconds * perSecondsWidth) - (marker.width() / 2)
    }, 1000, "swing");
    markerpills.html(currentdate.getHours() + ":" + currentdate.getMinutes());
    methods.markermove = setInterval(function() {
     currentdate = new Date();
     marker.css({
      left : marker.position().left + perSecondsWidth
     }, "fast", "swing");
     markerpills.html(methods.makezerodigit(currentdate.getHours()) + " : " + methods.makezerodigit(currentdate.getMinutes()));
     // methods.schedulemove(ele,perSecondsWidth);
    }, 1000);
   },
   schedulemove : function(ele,seconds) {
    var dragwrap = ele.find(".schedule-drag-wrap");
    var routewidth = $(".schedule-route:eq(0)").width() + $(".schedule-route:eq(1)").width();
    var maxleft = -(dragwrap.width() - ($(window).width() - routewidth));
    if (Math.abs(dragwrap.position().left) < Math.abs(maxleft)) {
     dragwrap.css({
      left : (dragwrap.position().left - (dragwrap.width)) + "px"
     });
    }
   },
   makezerodigit : function(digit) {
    return (String(digit).match(/^[0-9]$/)) ? "0" + digit : digit;
   },
   dragInit : function(ele) {
    var currentdaycol = $("[data-date='" + methods.currentdate + "']");
    ele.find(".schedule-drag-wrap").css({
     left : -(currentdaycol.position().left - 50) + "px"
    }).animate({
     left : -currentdaycol.position().left - 0 + "px"
    }, 1000, "swing", function() {
     methods.drag(ele);
     methods.setCurrentTimeMarker(ele);
    });
   },
   drag : function(ele) {
    methods.move = null;
    $(".schedule-drag-wrap", ele).on("mousedown", function(e) {
     var dragele = $(this), position = dragele.position();
     methods.move = {
      x : e.pageX,
      y : e.pageY,
      left : position.left
     };
    }).on("mouseup mouseleave", function(e) {
     var dragele = $(this);
     if (methods.move) {
      methods.move = null;
      dragele.removeClass("userselect-none cursor-move");
     }
    }).on("mousemove", function(e) {
     var dragele = $(this), position = dragele.position(), movedx, drag = true;
     if (methods.move) {
      methods.curmove = {
       x : e.pageX,
       y : e.pageY
      };
      var routewidth = $(".schedule-route:eq(0)").width() + $(".schedule-route:eq(1)").width();
      var maxleft = -(dragele.width() - ($(window).width() - routewidth));
      var xcondition = (methods.move.x > methods.curmove.x);
      dragele.addClass("userselect-none cursor-move");
      if (position.left <= maxleft && xcondition) {
       drag = false;
       dragele.css({
        left : maxleft
       });
      }
      if (position.left > -10 && !xcondition) {
       drag = false;
       dragele.css({
        left : 0
       });
      }
      if (drag) {
       //if direction right to left
       movedx = methods.move.left + (methods.curmove.x - methods.move.x);
       dragele.css({
        left : movedx
       });
      }
     }
    });
   },
   now : new Date(),
   currentdate : "",
   hmtosec : function(hours, identy) {
    var s = (hours.match(/\./)) ? hours.split(identy) : [hours, 0], h = s[0], m = s[1];
    h = (Number(h)) ? (h * 60) * 60 : 0;
    m = (m == 0) ? 0 : m * 60;
   
    return Number(h + m);
    
   },
   makeStringToObject : function(string) {
    var loc_string = String(string).split("|");
    var output = {};
    for (var i in loc_string) {
     var keyvalue = loc_string[i].split("~");
     output[keyvalue[0]] = keyvalue[1];
    }
    return output;
   }
  };
  return this.each(function() {
   methods.init($(this), $.extend({}, $.fn.schedule.setting, options));
  });
 };
 $.fn.schedule.setting = {};
})(jQuery);
```

and this is the error i am getting
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

**In service:**     `var deferred = $q.defer();
       $http.get('job.json')
    .success(function(response) {
     defer.resolve(response);
    }).error(function(error){
    console.log(error);
    })
        return deferred.promise;`

**In controller:**

```
var p=<serviceCall>
p.then(function(s){
$scope.ans=s;
})
```

The $q is used for getting synchronous response.for more details:https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: i tried this but this not getting data only so i tried to check if success is coming so i modified it
`var deferred = $q.defer();
   $http.get('job.json')
.success(function(response) {
 alert("success");
 defer.resolve(response);
 
}).error(function(error){
console.log(error);
})
    return deferred.promise;

});`
but still no luck could you explain it

Comment: that goes in the service. 
In the controller,
         var p=<serviceCall>
now in p.then(function(res){
$scope.big=response;
})

this is how you access promises

Comment: actually i am  new to angularjs can you tell me by service you mean another js file ??

Comment: yes... its just another js file and if you don't have one, then just modify your controller and instead of `var p=<serviceCall>`, make it `var p=$http.get('job.json')`

Answer (score 0):

Using promise.then you can update your value.

```
    var promise=$http.get('job.json');
    promise.then(function(result){
                  $scope.big=response;
    });
```

alternative way

```
   function getObj(callback){
    $http.get('job.json').success(callback);;
   } 

  getObj(function(result){
   console.log(result)
   // add your jquery code
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do a synchronous HTTP request, since the reponse (in your case it is the JSON file) can not be loaded instantly. However, `$http.get` returns a promise which is resolved when the request completes. You should do everything you want to do as soon as the JSON file has loaded inside the `then`-block of the promise.

```
$http.get('job.json').then(function (response) {
  $scope.big = response;
  // Do anything else you need to after JSON has been loaded.     
});
```

Comment: yes but the problem is before the json file is loaded some internal function is invoking a linked jquery function  that needed data from json file so thats y its giving error

Comment: Please edit your question to include details about that jQuery function and add the error messages, otherwise it is difficult to help.

Comment: done you can see the error its calling that 
`var currentdaycol = $("[data-date='" + methods.currentdate + "']");
    ele.find(".schedule-drag-wrap").css({
     left : -(currentdaycol.position().left - 50) + "px"
    }).`
before the response is over